# Как увеличить на 1 все записи через updateAll в Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Нужно увеличить на 1 все записи через updateAll. Нужно что-то вроде

```
Model::updateAll('number = number + 1', $conditions);
```

но так не выходит - требует массив. Еще пробовал так

```
Model::updateAll('number' => 'number + 1', $conditions);
```

но он передает значение просто как строку. Подскажите как это делается?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать так:

```
$model->updateCounters(array("number "=>"1"), $conditions);
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#updateCounters()-detail

Хотя возможно надо `updateAllCounters`. Хоть раньше было можно использовать и `updateCounters` в таком случае

Answer (score 1):

Пока писал вопрос, разобрался.
Надо было сделать так:

```
$expression = new Expression('`number` + 1');
Model::updateAll(['number' => $expression], $condition);
```